# Question about Inescapable Fisherman Variant

Tags: dnd-4e, swordmage

Specifically, I'm asking about the single-class Swordmage
Deva build in the bottom spoiler in this link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150916223017/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2898861#

> Race: Deva
>
> Class: Swordmage, Gladiator Champion, Soul of the World
>
> Feats:
>
> - Arcane Admixture (Sword Burst, Thunder)
> - Resounding Thunder
> - Mark of Storm
> - Heavy Blade Opportunity
> - White Lotus Riposte
> - Versatile Expertise
> - Total Aegis
> - Rapid Aegis Reaction
> - Greater Aegis of Shielding
> - Reserve Maneuver
> - Improved Defenses
> - Rapid Regeneration
> - MC Fighter
> - Polearm Momentum
> - Polearm Gamble
> - Blade Opportunist
> - Swordmage Implement
> - Expertise Improved
> - Swordmage Warding
>
> Powers At-Will: Sword Burst, Booming Blade
>
> Enc Powers: Thundering Vortex (L17), Dimensional Vortex (L3, reserve),
> Radiant Shield (L23), Circle of Devastation (L27)
>
> Daily Powers:
>
> Utility Powers:
>
> - Items: Weapon: Feyslaughter Glaive+6* (29) + Shard of the Mage (23)
> - Head: Helm of Opportunity+3 (24)
> - Neck: Amulet of Protection+6 (26)
> - Arms: Rythm Blade Wrist Razors+1 (3)
> - Armor: Magic Leather Armor (26)
> - Hands: Many Fingered Gloves (20)
> - Ring: Ring of Opal Rememberance (29)
> - Ring: Ring of Free Time (29)
> - Ring: Shadow Band (27)
> - Waist: Baldric of Shielding (19)
> - Feet: Rushing Cleats Tatoo: Eager Heroe's Tatoo  (paragon) (20)
>   Boon: Corellon's Boon (heroic) (8)
>   Battlescar: Reflexive Psychic Shroud (paragon) (17)
>
> *: Only if you often face enemies with teleportation, otherwise carnage weapon (or staggering for slide 8)
>
> Wonderous: Quarz Lens Solitaire (5), Dice of Auspicious Fortune x3
> (11), Saphire Scabbard (15), Keoghtom’s Ointment x2 (12), Foe Stone
> (12), Ritual Book, Rituals, Residuum

I just have a few questions:

1. The build takes Versatile Expertise. I'm assuming one of them is Heavy Blade, but what's the other choice?
2. The build seems to center on taking Polearm Momentum, which requires a slide of 2 to work, right? I know one of the units of slide is from Mark of Storm, but where's the other one?
3. This is just to make sure, but if I take Brawling Warrior or another Fighter MC feat, that fulfills the 'fighter' requirement for Polearm Momentum, right? I'm just mainly wondering because I have the Character Creator, and it won't seem to let me add P.M. despite having the MC and the requisite stats.

Comment: I *think* it'd be better to summarize the relevant information from the build in this post; Q&A should stand independently and I fear this one would become incomprehensible if the link died. (Now I know it's the web archive, but still....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1) Versatile Expertise

Versatile Expertise appears to be the go-to choice for builds that make both weapon & implement attacks. Swordmages definitely have some of both, so it's a reasonable pick in this case. They can use a heavy blade as both a weapon and an implement, but they still need a feat bonus on both kinds of powers' attack rolls.

#### 2) Polearm Momentum

Looking at the build, the 2nd square of slide seems to be coming from Rushing Cleats, a heroic-tier foot-slot magic item that increases push or slide distance on melee & close range powers.

#### 3) Fighter MC

Yes, taking a fighter multiclass feat makes you count as a fighter for the purposes of feat & paragon path prerequisites.

Comment: What do I choose for my second option for Versatile Expertise, though? I don't think I can choose Heavy Blade twice. Could I just take Heavy Blade Expertise instead?

Comment: @T.Smit I'll have to double check the wording on both feats. I *think* Heavy Blade Expertise only helps with weapon attacks, which is why Versatile Expertise is recommended. Versatile Expertise is *probably* improving heavy-blades-as-weapons for one choice and heavy-blades-as-implements for the other. Will be at home with books in a few hours.

Comment: @T.Smit One half of Versatile Expertise only counts for Weapon attacks, the other half only for Implement attacks. Thus, you can select the same option twice, if it's a weapon type, since they're affecting two different things. This isn't directly reflected in the builder, but the top list only has weapon types while the bottom list includes both weapon types and items that are strictly implements (e.g. holy symbols). Both lists apply to all attacks with those items, though, so if you're using the builder, just select Heavy Blades once and ignore the other list.

Comment: Versatile Expertise requires you to pick one implement type and one weapon type.  But unlike Weapon or Implement Expertise, it never specifies that its bonus is exclusive to "weapon attacks" or "implement attacks," so picking Heavy Blade from either category works for all kinds of attacks.  Heavy Blade Expertise does specify Weapon Attacks, so it wouldn't help on Implement Attacks.

Comment: Incidentally, given that the build uses Reserve Maneuver, your only non-Arcane attack power is the the Daily 20 from the PP.  White Lotus Dueling Expertise would work for all other attacks, and if combined with Arcane Familiar Disembodied Hand/Rakshasa Claw, give you interest proficiencies for item swapping.

Comment: Oh, I have one more question. Where does the build get regeneration? I noticed that Rapid Regeneration adds 8 to existing regeneration, but I have no idea where that's coming from.

Comment: @T.Smit Well, I've looked up pretty much every feat & magic item for both that variant and the original build, and I can't see anything that gives regeneration. It's possible that an earlier version of the build had regeneration from something, and the author missed swapping out that feat when they traded out whatever was giving regeneration.